# add many rows to df from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a simple, empty dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Description'])
```

Now i read a json file and with it I am creating a list of dictionary.

There are houndreds of dictionaries in that list which look something like this

```
{'id':'1', 'name':'some_name', 'description': 'some description'}
{'id':'2', 'name':'other_name', 'description': 'other description'}
```

I tried pushing all those dictionaries into my `data_table` variable but every way I tried, all the shapes or the indexes were messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Base on you description all `dict` in a `list`

```
youdf=pd.concat([pd.Series(x) for x in l],1).T
youdf
         description id        name
0   some description  1   some_name
1  other description  2  other_name
```

Data input

```
l=[{'id':'1', 'name':'some_name', 'description': 'some description'},
{'id':'2', 'name':'other_name', 'description': 'other description'}]
```